# How to host Next.js static website on Vercel without running build?

Tags: next.js, vercel

I made a website that is fully static. I can get the output files by running the following command locally

`next build && next export` which produces an output folder `out`

I'd like to simply put the `out` folder on Vercel but I'm not sure how to do that. When I connect my GitHub repository to Vercel it wants to build the whole project however I want to just give it the `out` folder and not have it run the build process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to Vercel Dashboard > Your Site > Settings > Build & Development Settings:

[image]

After configuring the settings as above, make sure `out` directory is not there in `.gitignore`, and then trigger the build (Deployments > Kebab Menu > Redeploy).

---

Note that using "Other" as framework preset may appear as if the code will not be optimized like other Next.js projects. This is not true. It will not impact your site's performance, and the assets will still be served from Vercel's Edge Network. I don't think that there is any difference between deploying this way and using Next.js preset to deploy a statically exported app; except the latter will consume your build minutes (which I don't think matters on Vercel).